# How to solve ID increment 1000 instead of 1 on each insert query in sql localdb

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I developed a software 2 years ago, suddenly clients reported that they cannot insert any employee anymore.

I looked at the logs I found that int16 cannot bear the inserted ID value that is bigger than 32000, while I have less than 100 rows in my database. I found that the ID is incrementing by 1000 instead of 1.

I searched the internet, I found that this issue is famous and its solution is adding something in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

My problem is that I am using sql localdb which does not have SQL Server Configuration Manager. I downloaded SQL Server Configuration Manager but its for the normal sql database not the localdb. How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Sounds like smallint isn't really the way to go.

Comment: Hint: Alter Table

Comment: @Max That is exactly what the OP meant when they said *"I found that this issue is famous and its solution is adding something in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. My problem is that I am using sql localdb which does not have SQL Server Configuration Manager"*. The actual duplicate addresses that specifically.